# How to load new page on click flash object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

Am working on a flash slider.I have 2 images embeded in it.. is it possible to click on the images and load a new html page?Here is my code:

```
    <object  classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="308" height="118" title="location">
      <param name="movie" value="<?=base_url()?>flash/home/locationsliders.swf">
      <param name="quality" value="high">
      <embed  src="<?=base_url()?>flash/home/locationsliders.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="308" height="118" ></embed>
    </object>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    AC_FL_RunContent('codebase',
   'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','width','308','height',
   '118','title','location','src',
   '<=base_url()>flash/home/locationsliders',
   'quality','high','pluginspage',
   'http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash',
   'movie','<?=base_url()?>flash/home/locationsliders' ); //end AC code
   </script>
```

Comment: Of course it's possible. But could you show us your AS code ?

Comment: Do you mean action script code? i have updated the code, this is the code am using so far to display the slider.I need to click on the slider and load a new page.

Comment: I meant the ActionScript code of the SWF (the source code) not the code used to embed it in the html page.

Comment: You can make changes in sourcecode of SWF file. in which on click of image open new html page Or call Javascript function using ExternalInterface.call() in which function will open HTML page.

Comment: When i open the swf file , i can see only some numbers only. Like this 4357 5309 34ff 0000 789c a477 6550 1c4c

Comment: Can anybody help me out on this?